# The parent::__construct(); function is causing problems as setData() says there is no object, for a simple block

Tags: magento

It's all coming from `parent::__construct();`

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on a non-object in
>   /home/desbest/public_html/clients/magentofull/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php
>   on line 129

```
<?php 
class Desbest_Brands_Block_Adminhtml_Brand_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'brands';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_example';
        $this->_mode = 'edit';

        $this->_addButton('save_and_continue', array(
                  'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Save And Continue Edit'),
                  'onclick' => 'saveAndContinueEdit()',
                  'class' => 'save',
        ), -100);
        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('brands')->__('Save Example'));

        $this->_formScripts[] = "
            function toggleEditor() {
                if (tinyMCE.getInstanceById('form_content') == null) {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'edit_form');
                } else {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'edit_form');
                }
            }

            function saveAndContinueEdit(){
                editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
            }
        ";
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if (Mage::registry('example_data') && Mage::registry('example_data')->getId())
        {
            return Mage::helper('brands')->__('Edit Example "%s"', $this->htmlEscape(Mage::registry('example_data')->getName()));
        } else {
            return Mage::helper('brands')->__('New Example');
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming you're dealing with an unadulterated version of Magento, take a look at line 129

```
127:    public function getFormHtml()
128:    {
129:        $this->getChild('form')->setData('action', $this->getSaveUrl());
130:        return $this->getChildHtml('form');
131:    }
```

You can see the attempt to fetch the child block named form fails to return an object.  Most likely, that's because up in the prepare layout method, Magento failed to instantiate the form

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    if ($this->_blockGroup && $this->_controller && $this->_mode) {
        $this->setChild('form', $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_blockGroup . '/' . $this->_controller . '_' . $this->_mode . '_form'));
    }
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

either because one of the following variables wasn't set on your class

```
$this->_blockGroup
$this->_controller
$this->_mode
```

or the class alias generated by the string

```
$this->_blockGroup . '/' . $this->_controller . '_' . $this->_mode . '_form'
```

was not a valid block class. Without knowing what you're trying to do, I'd suggest

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->_objectId = 'id';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'brands';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_example';
    $this->_mode = 'edit';    
    parent::__construct();
```

and ensuring you have a block class for the alias

```
brands/adminhtml_example_edit_form
//from
//$this->_blockGroup . '/' . $this->_controller . '_' . $this->_mode . '_form'
```

which will, most likely be a class named

```
class Desbest_Brands_Block_Adminhtml_Example_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: I've got the parameters for the construction setup fine, and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: What's the actual alias of the block that Magento attempts to instantiate with $this->_blockGroup . '/' . $this->_controller . '_' . $this->_mode . '_form'?

Comment: What's a block alias? All I know is that there is a class for brands/adminhtml_brand_edit_form which resides in app/local/Desbest/Brands/Block/Adminhtml/Brand/Edit/Form.php (PS. I changed `example` to `brand` from what was in the answer, but the classes pointing to each other, are all the same.)

Comment: The string "brands/adminhtml_brand_edit_form" is a class alias.  In a blank controller action or otherwise bootstrapped Magento page, what happens when you run the code. $test = new Desbest_Brands_Block_Adminhtml_Brand_Edit_Form?  Or the code Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->createBlock('brands/adminhtml_brand_edit_form');

Comment: What error are being logged with the blank page?  Have you tried running your system in developer mode and with the php display_errors ini set to "1"?

Comment: I have Magento setup to show exceptions on the webpage and I've renamed that special file that allows errors to be logged inside `var/log`. The code `public function indexAction() $test = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->createBlock('brands/adminhtml_brand_edit_form'); }` for the indexController, just shows a blank page and doesn't log anything.

Comment: Last tip — what's inside the variable $test?  Breaking this off as you   have enough to start debugging this on your own.  Best wishes.

Comment: Nothing is inside the $test variable. It's blank and was previously undefined. In php, if you have something like `$test = round(4.545, 7);` or `$test = execute('apples', 'bananas');` you can echo the variable, and it will print `true` or `false`. Also, how am I supposed to debug anything, if all I get is a blank page, and no error logs. http://codemagento.com/2011/02/grids-and-forms-in-the-admin-panel/

Comment: @AlanStorm Thanks , your answer helped me. I was having invalid module name under $this->_blockGroup = '';  in my Edit.php file for one of mu module.

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible, that your `Desbest_Brands_Block_Adminhtml_Brand_Edit.php` is not present in the according folder `Desbest/Brands/Block/Adminhtml/Brand/Edit`.